# How to install php55-mysql on Amazon Linux

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2

I did a yum search mysql on Amazon Linux and only the following are available:

```
php-mysql.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL databases
php-mysqlnd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL databases
php54-mysql.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL databases
php54-mysqlnd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL databases
php55-mysqlnd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL databases
php56-mysqlnd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL databases
```

How do I install php55-mysql? I do not want php55-mysqlnd as Native Driver returns Integer instead of String for queries.

Comment: have you tried adding a repository?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Vhortex Any idea where can I find the repository that contains that package?

Comment: I have not tried Amazon's linux so I can't really recommend an alternate repository. On cases like this, I first try the official repositories (php on this case)